# Interpreting an unusual use of comma during assignment in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, operators

I'm looking at a snippet from the cuda c programing guide guide, http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions

There is a statement in a snippet they gave which threw me for a loop and I've been having some trouble interpreting it ...

```
unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
```

I've gone through several similar questions on SE and I think I've got it but I'm still not sure ... my interpretation of the indicated line is that it is equivalent to:

```
unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull;
unsigned long long int assumed;
```

Assuming I'm correct, I don't really understand *why*, or what's happening. I know I can do something like

```
int a,b,c;
```

to declare 3 types of ints, but what happens when I mix assignment and declaration in one line?

Comment: 2016. and people still think C and C++ are the same language.

Comment: No. I think that this question is applicable to both languages.

Comment: @tobi303 Not at all.  This is a variable declaration not the comma operator.

Comment: tobi, I looked at that one and it didn't answer my question. Does the evaluation not do anything, or is it declaring the variable?

Comment: @tobi303: Not a comma operator. It's a *init-declarator-list*.

Comment: The answer is yes...try and avoid "yes/no" questions on SO

Comment: @NathanOliver haha yes of course. I was just too fast acting without thinking...

Comment: Give me a second and I will reword it to not be yes/no, because I'm still not clear on WHY I'm right.

Comment: If you want the answer for C, look at C11 draft standard n1570, *6.7 Declarations
Syntax
1
declaration:
declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list opt ; init-declarator-list:
init-declarator
init-declarator-list , init-declarator
init-declarator:
declarator
declarator = initializer*

Comment: As to why? --> likely it was simpler for a compiler to be written that allowed  mixed assignment/declaration than not and having to provide an error message.  Many earlier design decisions are based on simplicity of implementation than structure, grammar, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that this:

```
unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
```

Is the same as this:

```
unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull;
unsigned long long int assumed;
```

When declaring one or more variables, an initializer may optionally be specified.

From section 6.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 6 The  declaration  specifiers  consist  of  a  sequence  of 
>   specifiers  that  indicate  the  linkage, storage duration, and part
>   of the type of the entities that the declarators denote.  **The
>   init-declarator-list  is  a  comma-separated  sequence  of 
>   declarators,  each  of  which  may  have additional  type 
>   information,  or  an  initializer, or both.**   The declarators 
>   contain  the identifiers (if any) being declared.

Comment: Can I specify for individual ones? In any order? For example:

 int a,b=3,c,d=5; ?

Comment: You can keep initializing or not initializing until the cows come home. And by that time you'll have enough counters to keep track of a lot of cows.

Comment: Yes, that's basic syntax of the C language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will come along with a more technically accurate answer, but here's an anecdotal one that may help.

`int a;` is interpreted as "allocate enough bytes for an integer called 'a'"

`int a,b,c;` is interpreted as "allocate enough bytes for 3 integers called 'a', 'b', and 'c'"

You can *think* of the equals operator as a function call that returns the same reference it is acting upon. So the "return" value of `old = *address_as_ull*` is `old`.

As a side note you can mix and match pointers in as well, so long as the "end result" is an integer.

```
int fact(int n);
int
    a = 1, // an integer
    *p = new int(2), // a pointer initialized with the value 2
    (*fp)(int) = fact; // a function pointer to the function fact()
```

Beyond this kind of anecdote all I can say is "it's this way because someone decided it to be this way, and that's the standard". It's convenient to be able to declare a lot of variables with the same type this way. Maybe it helps compilers with optimization (can't really say). But certainly there's no reason for it *not* to be this way.